# Why are delays skipped in a Kotlin Flow inside a test?

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

To give a little bit of context: I'm trying to test a flow that has a delay inside of it. To test it well I want assert values at certain times and thus I have to control the virtual time. However, `delay(...)` seems to be skipped in tests. Take this example:

```
@Test
fun test(dispatcher: TestDispatcher) = runTest(dispatcher) {
    flow {
        emit(1)
        delay(10000)
        emit(2)
    }
        .flowOn(dispatcher)
        .test {
            assertEquals(1, awaitItem())
            assertEquals(2, awaitItem())
            awaitComplete()
        }
}
```

In the example I expect the `assertEquals(2, awaitItem())` to timeout, because `advanceTimeBy(10001)` wasn't called to move past the delay. However, this test finishes successfully, so it's just skipping the delay.

Does someone know why this is? How do I achieve what I want?

PS
The `TestDispatcher`  is a `StandardTestDispatcher` provided by a JUnit5 extension, which  also calls `Dispatchers.setMain` before the test. `.test { }` on the flow comes from the [Turbine](https://github.com/cashapp/turbine) library. Versions used for this example:

- Kotlin: 1.6.21
- Kotlin coroutines: 1.6.1
- Turbine: 0.8.0
- JUnit5: 5.8.2

PPS
With just coroutines the behaviour is as expected. Take the example below. If you remove the `advanceTimeBy` the test no longer works.

```
@Test
fun coroutineTest(dispatcher: TestDispatcher) = runTest(dispatcher) {
    var number = 0
    launch {
        number = 1
        delay(10_000)
        number = 2
    }
    
    advanceTimeBy(10_001)
    assertEquals(2, number)
}
```

Comment: I would expect the second `awaitItem()` call cause the flow to wait for the delay. It's defined behavior is to suspend until the next item arrives, isn't it? Is this test finishing in less than 10 seconds?

Comment: Yes, it's finishing in a few milliseconds

Answer (score 2):

[runTest()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-test/kotlinx.coroutines.test/run-test.html) by default will skip any delay() for you.

Comment: I read that indeed, but I thought that by using your own `TestDispatcher` delays wouldn't be skipped anymore. See the PPS I just added, that confirms that behaviour

Comment: "Delays in code that runs inside dispatchers that don't use a TestCoroutineScheduler don't get skipped" . Probably the TestDispatcher is not using a TestCoroutineScheduler ?

Comment: Looking at [the code](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/d3f21df63480c23bc25a89316c42c8202a029919/kotlinx-coroutines-test/common/src/TestCoroutineDispatchers.kt#L146),`StandardTestDispatcher` uses a `TestCoroutineScheduler` if you don't supply one (and I don't). FYI both test cases use the same `TestDispatcher`

Comment: The code in PPS is not doing the same thing. awaitItem() _waits until the next item is delivered_. Same thing will happen if you replace advanceTimeBy with advanceUntilIdle in the PPS code. delays are skipped in either case. It's just that the PPS code is _asserting_ before waiting until the coroutine is idle.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my understanding.

| runTest | Actual time to advance | Virtual time to advance |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `delay(1_000)` not in `launch` | 0s | 0s |
| `delay(1_000)` in `launch` | 0s | 1s |
| `delay(1_000)` in a dispatcher that doesn't use `TestCoroutineScheduler` (e.g. using `withContext`) | 1s | 1s |

In your case, `delay` in `fun test(…)` is skipped in both actual and virtual time because it is not in `launch`. So you don't need to use `advanceTimeBy`.

On the other hand, `delay(10_000)` in `fun coroutineTest(…)` is skipped in actual time but adds 10 seconds to the virtual time because it is in `launch`. So you have to use `advanceTimeBy`.